# Successful Preflight Request But 404 Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am working on a Spring Application with an Angular Client.
I added two new Rest Controllers, one of them working just fine, however there seems to be an issue with the other one of them.

When I call an endpoint of this controller I get a successful preflight request. But afterwards I get a 404. This is for all of the endpoints in this controller.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class PriceConfigRestController implements ApiRestController {

    public static final String URI_PRICECONFIG_BY_ID_INTERNAL = URI_PRICECONFIGS_INTERNAL + "/{priceConfigId}";
    public static final String URI_DELETE_PRICECONFIG_BY_ID_INTERNAL = URI_PRICECONFIGS_INTERNAL + "/{priceConfigId}";
    public static final String URI_PRICECONFIGS_BY_ORGANIZER_ID = URI_ORGANIZERS_INTERNAL + "/{organizerId}/priceconfigs";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PriceConfigRestController.class);

    private final PriceConfigService priceConfigService;

    public PriceConfigRestController(PriceConfigService priceConfigService) {
        this.priceConfigService = priceConfigService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = URI_PRICECONFIGS_INTERNAL, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<PriceConfigDto> createPriceConfig(@RequestBody @Valid @NotNull PriceConfigDto priceConfigDto){
        PriceConfigDto resultDto = priceConfigService.createPriceConfig(priceConfigDto);
        LOGGER.debug("PriceConfig with ID : " + resultDto.getId() + " created: Response: " + HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(priceConfigDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = URI_DELETE_PRICECONFIG_BY_ID_INTERNAL, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> deletePriceConfigById(@PathVariable Long priceConfigId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        priceConfigService.deletePriceConfigById(priceConfigId);
        LOGGER.debug("Removed priceConfig with ID: " + priceConfigId + " Response: " + HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Boolean.TRUE, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = URI_PRICECONFIG_BY_ID_INTERNAL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<PriceConfigDto> getPriceConfigById(@PathVariable Long priceConfigId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        PriceConfigDto priceConfigDto = priceConfigService.getPriceConfigById(priceConfigId);
        LOGGER.debug("PriceConfig ID: " + priceConfigId + " Response: " + HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(priceConfigDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = URI_PRICECONFIGS_BY_ORGANIZER_ID, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<PriceConfigDto>> getPriceConfigsByOrganizerId(@PathVariable Long organizerId) {
        List<PriceConfigDto> priceConfigDtos = priceConfigService.getPriceConfigsByOrganizerId(organizerId);
        LOGGER.debug("PriceConfigsByOrganizerId ID: " + organizerId + " Response: " + HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(priceConfigDtos, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I am sure the url I am calling is correct.
I was thinking there could be an issue with my client so I used postman to test the request.

However also using postman I get a 404 response.

Browsing other questions I found a lot of answers suggesting the Controller to be in a folder not scanned and therefore the Controller not being registered.

However I don't know how to check if a Controller has been registered.
Additionally we use a specific folder structure which is also used for both new Controllers.

Any help would be appreciated as I am a quite stuck

Comment: Please check if any error message shows in the server console. Also make sure on the client side you provide the correct "content-type" http header matched the server side.

Comment: @Stone There is no error in the console and the content-type looks correct